# Powershell Script that inserts 2 new strings into an existing XML config file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an existing XML Config File but would like to update the file with 2 new strings into the Run1, Run2 etc - specific to 2 VMs only across our Estate.

**Existing Config File:**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Run1" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run3" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run4" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run5" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run6" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run7" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run8" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run9" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run10" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run11" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run12" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run13" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Run14" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
   
   <Run1>
    <!-- FTP collection of AFP from QA WRE1010-->
    <add key="XsltFilePath" value="F:\OMWireTransformationService\XSLT\BBCWire2OM.xsl"/>
    <add key="InputDirectory" value="F:\WireDistribution\External\Original\OMWT1"/>
    <add key="InputFileFilter" value="*.xml"/>
    <add key="ErrorSubFolderName" value="ERROR"/>
    <add key="OutputDirectory" value="F:\WireDistribution\Outgoing"/>
    <add key="ResolveExternalDTDs" value="false"/>
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="F:\OMWireTransformationService\LOG\OMWTSLog_Run1.txt"/>
    <add key="FtpEnabled" value="sFtp"/> <!-- allowed values(first is default): "false", "true" or "Ftp", "sFtp", "sFtpCheckKnownHosts" -->
    <add key="FtpServer" value="10.57.36.80"/>
    <add key="FtpDirectory" value="/data/afp/"/> 
    <add key="FtpUser" value="omqalive"/>
    <add key="FtpPassword" value="omLIVE22!"/>
    <add key="FtpFilesRemoveEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="FtpTransportAsciiEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="FtpModeActiveEnabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="FtpPollingSeconds" value="6"/>
  </Run1>

   <Run3>
    <!-- FTP collection of internal wires -->
    <add key="XsltFilePath" value="F:\OMWireTransformationService\XSLT\BBCWire2OM.xsl"/>
    <add key="InputDirectory" value="F:\WireDistribution\External\Original\OMWT3"/>
    <add key="InputFileFilter" value="*.xml"/>
    <add key="ErrorSubFolderName" value="ERROR"/>
    <add key="OutputDirectory" value="F:\WireDistribution\Outgoing"/>
    <add key="ResolveExternalDTDs" value="false"/>
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="F:\OMWireTransformationService\LOG\OMWTSLog_Run3.txt"/>
    <add key="FtpEnabled" value="sFtp"/> <!-- allowed values(first is default): "false", "true" or "Ftp", "sFtp", "sFtpCheckKnownHosts" -->
    <add key="FtpServer" value="10.57.36.80"/>
    <add key="FtpDirectory" value="/data/omintwires/"/> 
    <add key="FtpUser" value="omqalive"/>
    <add key="FtpPassword" value="omLIVE22!"/>
    <add key="FtpFilesRemoveEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="FtpTransportAsciiEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="FtpModeActiveEnabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="FtpPollingSeconds" value="6"/>
  </Run3>

   <Run4>
    <!-- FTP collection of PA -->
    <add key="XsltFilePath" value="F:\OMWireTransformationService\XSLT\BBCWire2OM.xsl"/>
    <add key="InputDirectory" value="F:\WireDistribution\External\Original\OMWT4"/>
    <add key="InputFileFilter" value="*.xml"/>
    <add key="ErrorSubFolderName" value="ERROR"/>
    <add key="OutputDirectory" value="F:\WireDistribution\Outgoing"/>
    <add key="ResolveExternalDTDs" value="false"/>
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="F:\OMWireTransformationService\LOG\OMWTSLog_Run4.txt"/>
    <add key="FtpEnabled" value="sFtp"/> <!-- allowed values(first is default): "false", "true" or "Ftp", "sFtp", "sFtpCheckKnownHosts" -->
    <add key="FtpServer" value="10.57.40.44"/>
    <add key="FtpDirectory" value="/data/pa/"/> 
    <add key="FtpUser" value="omprodtest"/>
    <add key="FtpPassword" value="omTST88!"/>
    <add key="FtpFilesRemoveEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="FtpTransportAsciiEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="FtpModeActiveEnabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="FtpPollingSeconds" value="6"/>
  </Run4>
```

**New Strings to be added:**

```
<add key="LogFileSizeLimit" value="40"/> // limit size for log file in Megabyte
<add key="LogFileArchiveCount" value="2"/> // how many files is desired
```

But I would like these new strings precisely between the <add key="LogFilePath" & <add key="FtpEnabled"; if possible.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: $pathToConfig = "F:\OMWireTransformationService\OMWireTransformationService.exe.config" #put your path here

Comment: #force the config into an XML
$xml = [xml](get-content $pathToConfig)

#find the node to insert after
$foundNode = $xml.configuration.Run1

#build new node by hand and force it to be an XML object
$newNode = [xml]@"
<add key="LogFileSizeLimit" value="40"/> 
<add key="LogFileArchiveCount" value="2"/>
"@

#add new node AFTER the configsections node
$newNode = $xml.ImportNode($newNode.appSettings,$true)
$xml.configuration.InsertAfter($newNode,$foundNode) |out-null

#save file
$xml.Save("$pathToConfig.CHANGED.XML")

Comment: But I want it to run through all the sections (Run1, Run2, Run3 etc) in the Configuration File

Comment: Check out xPath, with selectNodes you can loop through all hits

Comment: Thanks @guiwhatsthat - do you have an example I can work against please.